# How can I enforce camelCasing in cosmos/EF when my .NET classes are named with PascalCasing?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, azure-cosmosdb

I am encountering this error when trying to query data from cosmos:

> The partition key for entity type 'DataModel' is set to
> 'partitionKey', but there is no property with that name.

Here is what my DataModel class looks like:

```
public class DataModel
    {
        /* Properties - Serializable */
        public string Id { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public int? Index { get; set; } = null;
        public string? PartitionKey { get; set; } = null;
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public bool Locked { get; set; } = false;
        public string? LockedUser { get; set; } = null;
        public List<Record> Records { get; set; } = new List<Record>();
        public List<Field> Fields { get; set; } = new List<Field>();

        /* Properties - Not-Serializable */
        [JsonIgnore]
        [NotMapped]
        public Record? RootRecord = null;
        [JsonIgnore]
        [NotMapped]
        public BehaviorSubject<Record?> RootRecordBH = new BehaviorSubject<Record?>(null);
    }
```

Here is how I am implementing OnModelCreating:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<DataModel>().Property(x => x.Id).ToJsonProperty("id");
            modelBuilder.Entity<DataModel>().Property(x => x.Index).ToJsonProperty("index");
            modelBuilder.Entity<DataModel>().Property(x => x.PartitionKey).ToJsonProperty("partitionKey");
            modelBuilder.Entity<DataModel>().Property(x => x.Name).ToJsonProperty("name");
            modelBuilder.Entity<DataModel>().Property(x => x.Locked).ToJsonProperty("locked");
            modelBuilder.Entity<DataModel>().Property(x => x.LockedUser).ToJsonProperty("lockedUser");
            modelBuilder.Entity<DataModel>().Property(x => x.Records).ToJsonProperty("records");
            modelBuilder.Entity<DataModel>().Property(x => x.Fields).ToJsonProperty("fields");
            modelBuilder.Entity<DataModel>()
                .ToContainer("DataModels")
                .HasPartitionKey("partitionKey");
        }
```

My understanding is that you can control property names in cosmos by using the .ToJsonProperty in OnModelBuilding() when using EF/EFCore, although this appears to be doing nothing.
I'm not quite sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Probably `.HasPartitionKey("name")` expecting the name to match the model property name, not the provider json name. Try the expression tree override? `.HasPartitionKey(x => x.PartitionKey)`

Comment: `.HasColumnName()` can be used for individual properties to specify the naming EF should use in the DB. Often I use the `[Column("name")] attribute within the entity for this, such as when I'm working with PostgreSQL and existing schemas. Another option would be to have a look at this implementation to perform the renaming. (https://andrewlock.net/customising-asp-net-core-identity-ef-core-naming-conventions-for-postgresql/) it is for PostgreSQL and snake_case, but could be adapted for camelCase.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to execute the code shared in question and able to save data in CosmosDB with camelCasing format. My data model class has PascalCasing.

The only change done in the code is `.HasPartitionKey(x=>x.PartitionKey);` As mentioned by [Jeremy Lakeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4139809/jeremy-lakeman) in comment HasPartitionKey method accepts model property name not the json name.

Also to execute the code I have used below nuget packages and their respective version.

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos 7.0.1
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.1

**References:-**

- [EF modeling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/)
- [Azure Cosmos DB Provider - EF Core | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)
- [HasPartitionKey Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.cosmosentitytypebuilderextensions.haspartitionkey?view=efcore-7.0)